# Which of these 2 algorithms is more efficient?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, modulus, coding-efficiency

I was writing some code and I came up with 2 functions for wrapping around an array from the left. I named it negative modulo because it is similar to wrapping around an array from the right using modulus. I realize the performance implications are negligible on a small scale, but I would like to know which one is more efficient. What do you guys think?

```
static int negative_modulo(int a, int b)
    {
        int val1 = Math.Abs(a);
        if (val1 <= b)
            return b + a;
        else
            return b - (val1 % b);
    }

    static int negative_modulo2(int a, int b)
    {
        int val1 = Math.Abs(a);
        int n = val1 / b + 1;
        return a + b * n;
    }
```

Comment: I think that isn't Java, or you wrote your own version of `Math.abs`... also why can't you benchmark it?

Comment: Before testing which one is faster, make sure both work correctly.

Comment: The two methods don't do the same thing. Check carefully which one is right!

Comment: pbabcdefp is right, there are different results for both methods

Answer (score 1):

> What do you guys think?

Here's what I think ...

1. I think you are *most likely* wasting your time with micro-optimizing this.  In most cases, the difference in performance in code fragments like this is too small to make a significant difference to the overall performance of your program.

   It is much more important that the code works correctly.  Focus on that *before* you spend (or waste) your time on performance.
2. I also think that asking what people *think* is faster is a pointless exercise.

If you really want to know, you need to write a proper micro-benchmark, measure and compare the results.  However, that writing Java micro-benchmarks that give reliable results is NOT straight-forward.  Therefore you would be advised to use a framework such as Calliper for your benchmarks.